Test not executing code inside subscription callback when using GraphQL Yoga
I have a very simple dummy server with: Node.js + GraphQL + Apollo Server & Link that I'm migrating to Yoga Server & Link.
The Yoga version uses the same logic / idea as the Apollo version, just changed the necessary things.
You have the project repo here: https://github.com/zeuscronos/yoga-issue
On commit: "apollo server + test" you have the Apollo version while on commit: "yoga server + test" you have the Yoga version.
The Apollo version works as expected, i.e.:

the test executes the code inside the subscription callback
the test process finishes properly

In the other hand, the Yoga version has issues:

the test doesn't execute the code inside the subscription callback
the test process doesn't finish properly

Demo
Apollo Server + Test
https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-hhdwqx-rk8lne?file=src%2Findex.js,src%2Ftest.js
All good with Apollo Server + Apollo Link...

Yoga Server + Test
https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-hhdwqx-owkeze?file=src%2Findex.js,src%2Ftest.js
Hanging when using Yoga Server + Yoga Link...

Steps to Reproduce the Bug or Issue
$ yarn
$ yarn start # terminal 1
$ yarn test  # terminal 2

Any idea on how to solve this issue?
Thanks!
